# Automatically calculate is daylight savings from timezone offset in php

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I have a select where users choose their time zone. Currently I also have a toggle `is daylight savings`. I believe I should be able to remove the toggle for daylight savings and figure it out automatically via **PHP**. Currently I store, the time zone offset, i.e.

```
-08:00
```

or

```
+01:00
```

Is it possible using just that offset to figure out if it is daylight savings or not?

Comment: Answer is no.  One timezone that is -8 may observe DST and another may not, so you need the actual timezone.

Comment: So the recommended solution is to store not the offset, but the timezone name `Europe/Amsterdam`?